# Sum of random variables of strictly stationary series

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, time-series

If we know that the distribution of $(X_t, X_{t+1}, \dots, X_{t+h})$ and the distribution of $(Y_t, Y_{t+1}, \dots, Y_{t+h})$ are independent of $t$, for every $h \in \mathbb{N}$, does this imply that the distribution of $(X_t + Y_t, \dots, X_{t+h}+ Y_{t+h})$ is also independent from $t$?

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Comment: I gave it an up vote :) I would like to see maybe some conditions for when this is the case. 

Thank you for helping!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301363/showing-a-moving-average-is-strictly-stationary-if-underlying-sequence-is-strict?rq=1 
Example of a case where this is OK.

Comment: "I would like to see maybe some conditions for when this is the case" And how are we supposed to know that this is what you would like? Divination, maybe?

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily. Consider $(X_t)$ i.i.d. with a symmetric distribution and $Y_t=(-1)^tX_t$. Then $(X_t)$ and $(Y_t)$ are stationary but $X_t+Y_t$ is alternatively $0$ and $2X_t$ hence $(X_t+Y_t)$ is not stationary.